# (PyQt5) Create list of QLineEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlineedit

How to make a list of line editors without many variables? (smth like `self.line_1 = QLineEdit(self), self.line_2 = QLineEdit(self), ... , self.line_9000 = QLineEdit(self)`)

For example, I want to create this

[image: list of QLineEdit]

window with ability to get access to each element.
A simple cycle does not provide access to **each** element, only last. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make widgets as you said - cycle,
and you can access to the widget with using layout.itemAtPosition

it would go like this :

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
for i in range(list_length):
    line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
    layout.addWidget(line_edit)
```

to access the widget :

```
def access_widget(int):
    item = layout.itemAtPosition(int)
    line_edit = item.widget()
    return line_edit
```

now you can access to the designated QLineEdit.

Answer (score 0):

```
layout = QFormLayout()    
self.alphabet_line_edits = dict.fromkeys(['а', 'б', 'в', 'г'])
for letter in self.alphabet_line_edits:
    line_edit = QLineEdit()
    layout.addRow(letter, line_edit)
    self.alphabet_line_edits[letter] = line_edit

def button_clicked(self):
    print(self.alphabet_line_edit['б'].text())
```